# How to merge table and match names for column with multiple factors

Tags: r

I want to merge these two tables but couldn't find a better way to do it. Normally if I use merge it would have to have at least one column matching each other...

```
data<-data.frame(A=c("A1","A2","A3","A4"),B=c("13131,256","12141","256","684"))
   A         B
1 A1 13131,256 
2 A2     12141
3 A3       256
4 A4       684
```

and I want to merge column B according to the table below:

```
BNAME<-data.frame(NAME=c("Red","Green","Yellow","Black"),B=c("13131","256","12141","684"))
    NAME     B
1    Red 13131
2  Green   256
3 Yellow 12141
4  Black   684
```

so the final format should look like:

```
  A         B      NAME
1 A1 13131,256 Red,Green
2 A2     12141    Yellow
3 A3       256     Green
4 A4       684     Black
```

Is there a fast way to get this done?

Thanks a lot!!

Linp

Comment: +1 for reproducible example and showing desired output.

Comment: I agree with @SimonO101, but in the future, also do try to share what you've tried and where you got stuck....

Comment: will do. :) @Ananda Mahto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it in two steps. Firstly splitting the ID's you have in `data$B` according to your delimiter (`","` in this case), and then using these to get the relevant colour names from `BNAME` using `which` in the second command. The `*apply` family will be useful here to iterate over each element in your column:

```
ids <- sapply( data$B , function(x) c( strsplit( x , "," ) ) , USE.NAMES = FALSE )
[[1]]
[1] "13131" "256"  

[[2]]
[1] "12141"

[[3]]
[1] "256"

[[4]]
[1] "684"

data$NAME <- lapply( ids , function(x) BNAME$NAME[which( BNAME$B %in% x )] )
   A         B       NAME
1 A1 13131,256 Red, Green
2 A2     12141     Yellow
3 A3       256      Green
4 A4       684      Black
```

Comment: +1. This would have been my approach [until my new package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18215341/1270695) :) But a couple of points: (1) You seem to have assumed that both `data.frame`s used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. With the data as they have presented it in the question, the "NAME" column would be converted to the integer values for the factors unless you stick some `as.character`s in there. (2) The "NAME" column in your output is a `list`, which I'm comfortable with, but might trip up many users, especially since it is incompatible with things like `write.csv`.

Comment: Just put this into my code and all worked out. Thanks. :) In follow up with @AnandaMahto 's comment. (1). My data output was factor which does not work in this format, did have to change it to character. (2). yes, the output is a list and I did have to write to csv file. Threw in a pplist(unlist()) to make it work. :) Thanks for the great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Brand new on CRAN is a package I contributed called "[splitstackshape](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html)". It can be handy for a problem like this.

First, install the package and load it:

```
install.packages("splitstackshape", 
                 repos = "http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/", 
                 type = "source")
library(splitstackshape)
```

Split your "B" column, reshape it into a "long" dataset, and `merge` it with your "BNAME" data set.

```
x <- merge(concat.split.multiple(data, "B", direction="long"), 
           BNAME, sort = FALSE)
x
#       B  A time   NAME
# 1 13131 A1    1    Red
# 2 12141 A2    1 Yellow
# 3   256 A3    1  Green
# 4   256 A1    2  Green
# 5   684 A4    1  Black
```

^^ I would actually probably stop there. That would be much more convenient to work with than a data set where values are pasted together. But if you want to go that other step, use `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(cbind(B, NAME = as.character(NAME)) ~ A, 
          x, paste, collapse = ",")
#    A         B      NAME
# 1 A1 13131,256 Red,Green
# 2 A2     12141    Yellow
# 3 A3       256     Green
# 4 A4       684     Black
```

Comment: Ohhh I did not know this package before. Going to try it out! :P Thanks @Ananda Mahto !

Comment: @linp, it's brand new. If you find any bugs, let me know!